# async function not working when called in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

In angular, I'm using service to get the current location of the page an change the title of the page accordingly and for that, I'm using an *async* function which is working in normal case when a button is pressed but when the page loads and in `ngOnInit` it does not work in order.

```
async getPageName(): Promise < any > {

    await this.router.events.subscribe(event => {

        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            console.log("url ", event.url);
            var index = this.pageNameHeader.findIndex(function(page) {
                return page.location == event.url.replace("/", "");
            })
            this.pageName = this.pageNameHeader[index].name
        }
    });
    console.log(this.pageName, " initialize");

    return this.pageName;
}
```

controller

```
  this.commonService.getPageName().then(data=>{
  this.pageName = data
})
```

in the normal case the second log is coming in order but in `ngOnInit` it comes first.I'm not using observable here to return data because before the `event.subscribe` completes ,the `getPageName` function returns an empty string i.e old data.

Comment: I don't think you can await observables. You would have to pipe and tap for what you are doing in the subscribe callback and then call `toPromise` instead of `subscribe` for this to work.

Comment: i'm not using observable over here instead of it i'm using promise so as to use async await feature

Comment: But `this.router.events` returns an observable. Furthermore, `this.router.events.subscribe` returns a `Subscription` which you can not await at all. Also, you're returning `this.pageName` which is not a `Promise`, it's a `string`. You should really use some proper IDE to tell you about those mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite to use a proper promise should help

```
getPageName(): Promise <any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                console.log("url ", event.url);
                var index = this.pageNameHeader.findIndex(function(page) {
                    return page.location == location.pathname.replace("/", "");
                });
                if (index) {
                    resolve(this.pageNameHeader[index].name);
                } else { 
                    reject();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then you can do

```
async ngOnInit() {
  this.pageName = await this.getPageName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are awaiting a `Subscription` object, which is neither a Promise nor a Promise-like.

You can convert your `Observable` into a `Promise` using the `toPromise` method:

```
const event = await this.router.events.toPromise();
if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The `await` keyword works only on `Promise` object, but `this.router.events.subscribe()` expression returns a `Subscription` object.

You should try using the `toPromise()` method of observables:

```
async getPageName(): Promise < any > {
    await this.router.events.toPromise().then(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            console.log("url ", event.url);
            var index = this.pageNameHeader.findIndex(function(page) {
                return page.location == location.pathname.replace("/", "");
            });
            this.pageName = this.pageNameHeader[index].name
        }
    });
    console.log(this.pageName, " initialize");
    return this.pageName;
}
```